# Why am I not seeing a loading screen in my application on OS 3.1, but I am on 4.0?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a loading screen that appears when my application loads on an iPhone 3G running OS 4.0, but not on an iPhone 3G S running 3.1.2.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the missing link was that the loading-screen has to be named Default.png. it is NOT enough, that you have the file in the info.plist - or it is just enough for a 3g maybe.

Comment: The UIKit key UILaunchImageFile was first made available on iPhone OS 3.2: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html , so your 3.1-running device would not know how to handle it.  In that case, you need to fall back to the old way of making sure the startup image is named Default.png.